# using chown in linux

Tags: permissions, users, files

I want to assign www-data user full rights in folder /var/www/ and all of the files inside this folder.

I have tried `chown www-data /var/www/`

Comment: Note that you'll have to run `chown` as root, e.g. `sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/`.

Answer (score 9):

You need to do `chown -R www-data /var/www/` (`-R` means recursive).

Answer (score 2):

Use the "-R" switch to recursively change everything in a directory

```
chown -R www-data /var/www/
```